# Matlab shows coefficient more than needed

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to find the coefficient of butterworth filter of order 5, and I get 11 coefficient, while I have to get only 6. Following is the code I am using:

```
[y, Fs] = wavread('C:\Users\mamoun\Desktop\audio.wav');
[b,a]=butter(5,[200 800]/(Fs/2));
```

Here is the coefficients:

```
b =

   1.0e-05 *[0.0125, 0, -0.0627, 0, 0.1254, 0, -0.1254, 0, 0.0627, 0,  -0.0125]


a =

    [1.0000, -9.7076, 42.4256, -109.9240, 186.9906, -218.2146, 176.9209, 
     -98.4038, 35.9343, -7.7796, 0.7583]
```

Should I ignore the zeros in vector b and the associated numbers in vector a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read in Matlab documentation the following:

[z,p,k] = butter(n,Wn,'ftype')

"'bandpass' for an order 2*n bandpass filter if Wn is a two-element vector, Wn = [w1 w2]. The passband is w1 < ω < w2. Specifying a two-element vector, Wn, without an explicit 'ftype' defaults to a bandpass filter"

So this function returns coefficients fro 2*n filter in case of bandpass